# Is it safe to use AtomicBoolean for database locking in Scala/Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, scala, java.util.concurrent

I have an application where I want to ensure that a method is called at most once concurrently, say when updating user balance in a database.

I am thinking of using the following locking mechanism: (showing Scala code below, but should be similar with Java Lambdas):

```
object Foo{
    val dbLocked = new java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean(false)

    def usingAtoimcDB[T](f: => T):T = {
        if (dbLocked.get) throw new Exception("db is locked")
        dbLocked.set(true)
        try f
        finally dbLocked.set(false)    
    }
}
```

Is this safe to use when `usingAtoimcDB` may be called concurrently?

EDIT: The corrected code below, as pointed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39033507/243233):

```
def usingAtoimcDB[T](f: => T):T = {
  if(dbLocked.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
   //db is now locked
   try f
   finally dbLocked.set(false)
  } else {
   //db is already locked
   throw new Exception("db is locked")
  }
}
```

EDIT 2:

Using a spinloop. Is this also ok?

```
def usingAtoimcDB[T](f: => T):T = {
  while (!dbLocked.compareAndSet(false, true)) {Thread.sleep(1)}
  try f
  finally dbLocked.set(false)
}
```

EDIT3: Based on the answers and comments below, I am also considering using queues.

Comment: Is it safe to use it like this in Java ? If yes then it will be safe fro Scala.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh added Java tag, so Java people can answer this.

Comment: The code you posted above is not thread-safe; two threads can get past the `if (dbLocked.get)` call and both set the atomic boolean. You must use the `compareAndSet` method to make it atomic. A class such as `java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock` would be more appropriate here than an `AtomicBoolean`.

Comment: @Jesper what about using `compareAndSet` as pointed in the answer by leshkin?

Comment: That's what I said, you must use `compareAndSet` to make it atomic - without this it is not thread-safe.

Comment: @Jesper any particular disadvantage of using `AtomicBoolean` with `compareAndSet` compared to using `java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock`?

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it should work as espected. I would slightly modify your function using `compareAndSet` call.

`compareAndSet` method has the advantage to be an atomic operation - there are no race conditions and the value will be changed atomically.

```
def usingAtoimcDB[T](f: => T):T = {
  if(dbLocked.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
   //db is now locked
   try f
   finally dbLocked.set(false)
  } else {
   //db is already locked
   throw new Exception("db is locked")
  }
}
```

Comment: @Jus12 hm, although the code looks correct to me, I dont like sleeping threads. You simply waste your CPU time with waiting / spinning. I would suggest to return immediately after check (with exception or some error code) and then sleep. In order to make it more efficient you can wait with expenential growing interval, like 2ms, 4ms, 16ms ...

Comment: I can remove the sleep and just have a while loop. I'm still testing which is faster in my context.

Answer (score 7):

***Inadvisable.*** You are requesting that the same pieco of code running in the same application instance on tha same server is the single point to do that transaction. There also is no provision to let this code stand-out. When you are retired, someone may start a second application instance or whatever.

Whereas a database commit/rollback is a quite simple and sure mechanism.

When you cannot write an integration (unit) test to ensure this sole point, then do not do it.

If you do it:

- Revoke rights to the table modifications for the normal database user
- Add a new database use who has sufficient right granted

And still: do not do it.

Comment: Points noted. Won't it be a complex web of commit/rollbacks if handling distributed DBs?

Comment: A distributed DB system has its own mechanism, like a master DB. On the software side, a special access might be offered, like just using the master DB or such. I admit, **a volatile atomic lock might still be useful**, but not as guarantee, but as one queueing optimisation.

Comment: The current design intention is the use only this as the entry point for the db. Also this will probably not be used on production but only prototype.

Comment: Then excuse my rigtheous pedantry. You might also consider locking a file in the DB directory or such, if time is no issue. Good luck.

Comment: no worries. Always good to hear the pros and cons of any approach. +1 from me.

Answer (score 4):

The code you posted above is not thread-safe, because you are not using an atomic check-and-set operation. Two threads can both be executing the `if (dbLocked.get)` statement at the same time and both get `false` as the answer, and then both will do `dbLocked.set(true)` and call `f`.

If you really want to use `AtomicBoolean`, then you must use `compareAndSet` as @leshkin already showed - this is an atomic operation that does the check and set in one go without the possibility of another thread doing the same thing at the same time, so that it is thread-safe.

You are using an `AtomicBoolean` as a lock here. There are classes in the standard Java library which are better suited (and specifically made) for this purpose; have a look at the package [`java.util.concurrent.locks`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/package-summary.html).

You could for example use class `ReentrantReadWriteLock`, which combines two locks for reading and writing. The write lock is exclusive (when it's locked, nobody else can read or write); the read lock is shared (when it's locked, nobody can write, but others can read at the same time). This allows for there to be multiple readers concurrently, but only one writer at a time, possibly improving efficiency (it's not necessary to make reading an exclusive operation).

Example:

```
import java.util.concurrent.locks._

object Foo {
  private val lock: ReadWriteLock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock

  def doWriteOperation[T](f: => T): T = {
    // Locks the write lock
    lock.writeLock.lock()
    try {
      f
    } finally {
      lock.writeLock.unlock()
    }
  }

  def doReadOperation[T](f: => T): T = {
    // Locks the read lock
    lock.readLock.lock()
    try {
      f
    } finally {
      lock.readLock.unlock()
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks good and allows fine grained locking. In my case, `f` contains multiple read and write operations interleaved in the code, so I would need some refactoring. `AtomicBoolean` or global `write lock` seems to be the easiest solution.

Comment: Can you comment on my EDIT2?

Comment: @Jus12 Why use a spinloop; why try to implement this yourself, when the JDK already has a whole set of well-tested and optimized lock classes? Just use the standard classes instead of implementing this yourself.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, using read/write locks would require editing the code of `f` (which is written by someone else). If that is so, then the easiest solution would be to use some sort of a wrapper without understanding the semantics of the operations in `f`.

Comment: @Jus12 if you want just one exclusive lock, use `ReentrantLock` instead of `ReentrantReadWriteLock`. See API docs of package [`java.util.concurrent.locks`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/locks/package-summary.html).

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Is there any semantic difference between a `ReentrantLock` and the `usingAtoimcDB` method in my code? Both seem to achieve the same thing. Are there any performance benefits?

Comment: @Jus12 No semantic difference, but the JDK's lock classes might be more efficient (use locks provided by OS or CPU).